# Build Automation for Django

Tags: python, django, build, build-automation

I'm pretty new to doing sysadmin stuff for my development and to the django framework. I want to have a different username/password for my local dev station and to my production environment.

I'm using dotcloud as the server. I can write a post install script (in python, bash, whatever) and it will execute it on every new push.

However I don't know how to go about this. Do I need to write this myself? is there a python/django build automation tools that will help me with that?

**Clarification**: how can I change `debug=false` in settings.py to true just on the server?

Comment: Have a look at [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/)? Or [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.0/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually import my development settings at the end of production settings.py, if my project is residing on a local directory structure.

You can also store your DB settings and other settings that are different in production and development in a separate file and remove them from your SVN, Git of whatever you use.

Just add this at the end of your settings.py:

```
try:
  from myapp.specific_settings import *
except ImportError:
  pass
```

In this case, specific_settings will be different in production and development environment.

If you want to dynamically choose between development and production servers use this at the end of settings:

```
import os
directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
if directory == '/home/yourname/development/':
    from myapp.development_settings import *
else:
    from myapp.production_settings import *
```

Note that I wrote this on top of my head and there might be some bugs in it. I will verify that when I go home.

Comment: this won't work, the names imported in `from package import module` are then namespaced as `module.DEBUG` for instance. Django will happily ignore any `production_settings.DEBUG` constant. You should import `*` from one or another module that contains actual settings.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for the accurate review.

Answer (score 3):

The django standard way is to use an environmanet variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. Point it to different settings and let both import a common settings module for common things:

```
# settings_production.py

from settings_common import *
DEBUG = False
DATABASES = {...}


# settings_development.py

from settings_common import *
DEBUG = True
DATABASES = {...}


# settings_common.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (...) # etc
```

You can also use an alternative strategy of using one main settings and import names from another one depending on some system condition, like getting `os.platform.node()` or `socket.gethostname()` and switch over that value (or part of it).

```
reversed_hostname_parts = socket.gethostname().split('.').reverse()
host_specific = {
    ('com', 'dotcloud'): 'production',
    ('local'): 'dev',
}

for index in range(len(reversed_hostname_parts)):
    identifier = tuple(reversed_hostname_parts[:index+1])
    if identifier in host_specific:
        extra_settings = host_specific[identifier]
        break
else: # executed when the loop has not been `break`ed
    extra_settings = 'dev'  # any default value


if extra_settings == 'dev':
    from development_settings import *
elif extra_settings == 'production':
    from production_settings import *
```

**EDIT: added link**

See https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings for other strategies.

Comment: I don't like the overhead of both answers, though I used the first answer. I don't think this should be in the app code - it should be a shell script for build automation or something like that. E.g. say I want to sprinkle debug code, should it be all around the code and I should remove it when deploying? I'm still searching for a better solution :)

Comment: e.g. html5 boilerplate build. like that.

Comment: debug logs should be filtered out by your production logging configuration anyway. On the other side, how could you expect your build system to tell "debug code" from the rest? Do you want to use two different codes depending on where it is deployed? It would probably have bad effect on your ability to test the code.

Comment: The only point in the boilerplate build that applies to a django project is the one whoch says "Removes development only code (any remaining console.log files, profiling, test suite)". Well, as already said, logging is managed in configuration, profiling is not done in app code, and tests should be in their `app/tests.py` modules that are not even read during the request/response phase, and which are nonetheless useful if you need to test in the production environment (being it different than the local one).